# Precreated values in the Python universe

Tags: python, datamodel, python-datamodel

As far as I know (correct me if I am wrong) there are some values created on startup by the Python interpreter.

**Is there a way of finding out which values these are?**

Comment: Other then reading the source code and/or documentation? No.

Comment: @freakish: but the information is correct? values are created on startup? There must be a PEP or something explaing that...

Comment: Obviously all builtin functions are values generated at startup as well. Several constant like `True, False, None` some strings (e.g. empty), integers between `-5` and `256` and probably more. The info is scattered around the docs. For example you can read about integers here: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html

Comment: @freakish thank you, If this is all the information that there is, please make it an answer. You already helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Check `globals()`, `locals()`, and `__builtins__`.

Example:

```
>>> '__name__' in locals()
True
>>> locals()['__name__']
'__main__'
```

And if you're in the interactive interpreter for example, `__file__` does not exist.

Running from script:

```
print('__file__' in locals())
```

prints:

```
True
```

Running in interactive interpreter:

```
>>> '__file__' in locals()
False
```

Comment: Niether globals nor locals nor any of your example (except for `__builtins__`) are created at Python's startup. They are created during execution of module/function.